# Remove Non Numeric values (*Unknown*) in my data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I need to remove the non-numeric values in my data frame. Because I only need numeric values to do quantiles, percentiles, etc. Below is my data.

```
dataL
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 12892 entries ]
648 Levels: *Unknown* .P 001 111110 111199 111219 111310 111331 111335 111336 111339 111419 ... N/A
```

As you can see there are character values like *Unknown*, .P, etc. And I need to remove those things to do percentiles, quantiles, etc.
This is what I did.

```
dataL[dataL == "NA" | dataL == "N/A" |dataL == "*Unknown*" |dataL == ".P" |dataL == "NULL"] <- NA
dataS <- na.omit(dataV)
```

But when I run the dataS it still has the character value  *Unknown*

```
dataS

678 Levels: *Unknown* 0111 0116 0119 0139 0173 0174 0175 0179 0181 0182 0211 0212 0252 0711 ... 9999
```

Comment: Redo your data entry. Just coerce any numeric column with `colClasses` at the time of `read.table` or `read.csv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could avoid this problem while specifying `na.strings` in the `read.csv/read.table`

```
dataL <- read.csv("file.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
   na.strings = c("NA", "N/A", "Unknown*", "NULL", ".P"))
```

---

The problem with the current approach is that these are `factor` columns and replacing those `levels` to `NA` still show the unused `levels`.  So, we need `droplevels` to remove the unused `levels`

```
dataS <- droplevels(na.omit(dataL))
```